# center overflowing div inside smaller div

Tags: css

I have a div with the id of #container, I have another div inside og it with the id of #content. The #content div has a larger size than the #container div, and I need it centeret horizontally and vertically inside of the #container div.

[image: illustration of the issue]

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS I have tried is.

```
#container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
#content {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Though the sizes of the divs in the example are static values, the height will be changing all the time, so a dynamic solution is needed.

Comment: Are the elements size set using pecentages?

Comment: Can you use script (JavaScript or jQuery)?

Comment: Not sure I can envisage a use case for this. What is the purpose of this structure & positioing?

Comment: Can't you solve your problem with just some 100px padding on your container ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can position them absolutely and then use CSS3 transforms to drag them back into place.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/45qQ3/)

**CSS**

```
#container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: #663399;
}
#content {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution @paulie_D. One little note, you only need to position the `#content` absolutely... `#container` can remain within the document flow with `position: relative;`

Comment: True...allowing for additional margins etc. which would tend to make it a little less dynamic as the margin value would need to be calculated (I think). I assume, however, that centering was a requirement but, frankly, I don't see practical reason for this structure/effect anyway.

Comment: I could see forcing an assortment of images to conform to a specific size (like a square) without whitespace or squishing/stretching by using `overflow: hidden;` on the container - maybe a portfolio site or for something like thumbnails

Comment: Hmmm, I think I'd go JS/JQ rather than that way. :)

Comment: Agreed, I would definitely go JS/JQ if it was my page.

Comment: The use is exactly what you mentioned above, for a portfolio site. Why would you prefer a JS solution rather to a CSS3 one?

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks, this helped me create centered vertical text in a table: https://jsfiddle.net/gw1fu6op/