# CSS: Horizontally centering in a container smaller than the actual element

Tags: html, css, slider, centering

I have a concept for a flexible sizing slider with background image (E.g. to be placed at the top of a web page). The visible part of the background image depends on the screen size.The width of the slider is always 100%. The slider height is fixed to `n` pixels. The concept is best shown in the image below.

[image: Concept: Flexible sizing page header slider with background image]

Also see this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e76m3qja/ and play around with the result panel's width.

My code almost works, but I'm not able to center the image horizontally in the visible (red) box. How can I achieve this? Are there existing solutions (preferably for bootstrap)?

There is a solution for a similar problem, but unfortunately it totally breaks my concept: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24635599/395879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution

Your HTML

```
 <div  class="dynamicIMG" /></div>
```

Your CSS

```
.dynamicIMG{
    width:100%;
    background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Holloways_beach_1920x1080.jpg/1280px-Holloways_beach_1920x1080.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    height: 100px; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;}
```

BOOM!

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/khaledalyawad/sud703z9/4/

Comment: So, I added the image as a CSS background image. I used the "cover" property to insure that the image is always taking the full width of the div. Then you can specify the required hight for your div.

Comment: The image background will automatically fill the div and centralize itself in the middle of the div

Answer (score 0):

If you delete :

```
.inner {
min-height: 360px;
min-width: 640px;
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 1280px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xdmt6czw/

Or you want to keep the same height ?

Comment: No, then it always scales. This does not crop left and right sides on small devices.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the image as a background-image; then use 0 height combined with padding-bottom as a percentage which will allow for responsive height. Removing any ugly white space around the containing div.

Then position it 50% 50% which will centre the image horizontally and vertically.

You could then use media queries to fix the height/width of the image when it reaches your desired width and height.

```
body { margin: 0; }

.outer {
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    min-width: 640px;

    padding-bottom: 27.8%;
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Holloways_beach_1920x1080.jpg/1280px-Holloways_beach_1920x1080.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .outer {
        padding-bottom: 0;
        height: 360px;
   }
}
```

**I made you a quick fiddle of your example here:** http://jsfiddle.net/iamcreative/e76m3qja/5/

Comment: This is also an interesting idea but does not solve my problem: The height is not fixed and it is not centered horizontally below 640px width

Comment: Actually it does center both horizontally and vertically. The background position: 50% 50%; makes sure it is 50% left and 50% from the top of the div.